# Does the first element (e.g. list[0]) of a linked list reference the head or the first node?

Tags: linked-list

Exactly what the title says.

Also: What would `list[0]` yield (if one were to implement linked list indexing) if the linked list contained just a head pointing to `null` (or the programming language in question's functional equivalent of `null`).

Finally: Would the length be 0 or 1 (with length referring to the number of elements in the list) if the linked list contained only a head pointing to `null`?

Comment: What implementation are you talking about? In linked list I would write by myself the head and the first node are the same. In any case, indexing (which is an untypical operation for lists, btw) and length should be data-based. not implementation-based. So `list[0]` should return the first element, the length should return the number of elements.

Comment: @dyukha I don't know what you mean by "What implementation are you talking about?" If the list had only a head and no elements had yet been appended, what would list[0] yield?

Comment: Also, whoever voted this down, could you explain why? I'm new to asking questions here.

Comment: It means that your question is unclear (this is why I downvoted it), and this is the first time you mentioned that you take `list[0]` of empty list. In such case your program should crash in some way (throw something like IndexOutOfBounds).

Comment: @dyukha Ok, I edited the question. Is that more clear?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Answers are "throw IndexOutOfBoundsException" and "0".